# relating poisson and exponential distributions

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Here is the entire question:

> A random variable Y follows an exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$. Given $Y = y$, another random variable X follows the Poisson distribution with $\lambda = y$. Show that $P(X = k) = \frac{\theta}{(1 + \theta)^{(k+1)}}$.

I know that $P(X = k) = \frac{e^{-y} y^k}{k!} $ but I don't know how to use the Y random variable to solve the equation.

Comment: You know the conditional $P(X = k\mid Y=y) = \frac{e^{-y} y^k}{k!}$.  To get the marginal $P(X = k)$ you need to integrate out $y$ using the distribution of $Y$

Comment: Thanks @Henry for the help.

Comment: Yes @callculus42, there's a part in this that solves my doubt. Thanks too.

Comment: @MatheusSousa Glad to Herr.